# The network path was not found

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms

Al momento de dar `click` en el `listbox` en donde me muestra la dirección IP en donde se encuentra ubicada la carpeta y ver los comentarios que tiene me arroja lo siguiente:

> IOException The network path was not found

La dirección que pongo es correcta y si me abre en el explorador. Mi duda es ¿Por qué no se muestra el contenido?

En la imagen muestra la dirección que es `\\10.49.127.12\CM_Users\Oscar Guerrero\projects\SAP Files\0` aquí se encuentran las carpetas que quiero ver en comentarios

[image]

Comment: Intenta abrir visual studio en modo administrador

Comment: el 0 final es una carpeta o forma parte del nombre del archivo?

Comment: @gbianchi el 0 es parte del nombre del archivo que hay dentro de la dirección.

Comment: perfecto, yo para descartar que ese no fuera el error... puede ser que el ejecutable no tenga permisos contra esa carpeta?

Comment: @gbianchi Lo que tambien identifique que realmente es que esta dirección esta mal 
"\\mxgdlm4trans01\SAP_Serialization_Files\0" + txtDelivery.Text + ".txt"  y me dice que no la encuentra , accedi a SQL Server y esta funcionando correctamente , que puede ser lo que este afectando?

Comment: que tiene que ver sql server?

Comment: Tienes razón me estaba llendo por otro lado y no interfiere el SQL Sere en el programa.

Comment: Esa es una dirección de red, necesitas un usuario que tenga accesos a esa carpeta, si estas 100% que tienes acceso a esa carpeta, prueba con ponerle la IP en lugar del nombre de la PC

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que no te estas conectando a ese equipo con un usuario y contraseña, entonces a la hora de conectarse sin usuario, falla y te aparece el mensaje de error, incluso si la carpeta compartida es pública.

Debes establecer una conexión con esa ruta indicando un usuario y una contraseña:

Para ello vamos a usar linea de comandos, y lo vamos a hacer con NET USE:

```
Dim pcs As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
Dim command As String = "NET USE " + Ubicacion + " /user:" + username + " " + password
pcs.Arguments = command
Process.Start(pcs)
command = " copy \"" + filePath + "\"  \"" + directory + filenameToSave + "\""
pcs.Arguments = command
Process.Start(pcs)
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

El txtDelivery.Text debería ir entre comillas simples para hacerle saber al String que ese dato es una cadena de texto (así sean números).

Quedaría:

```
Dim Destino as String = "\\10.49.127.12\CM_Users\Oscar Guerrero\Projects\SAP Files\0'" + txtDelivery.Text + "'.txt"
```